# Top users(comments)

Tags: php, sql

I have a users table and a comments table and I want to select from users the top users that have the biggest amount of comments from the comments table and order them by numbers of comments

Just the forum comments should be counted(type can be forum,picture,news etc)

table structure

users

```
id | username | password
```

comments

```
id | text | type | author_id
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Define *top users*/*biggest amount*.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
   u.id,u.username,u.password ,count(c.id) as total
FROM
   users u
JOIN comments c on c.author_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This should do the trick, try and let us know how it worked out for you

**UPDATE**
For details on how to do this you will fall inlove with [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641)

**Update : New Link, old one is broken** [Databases](http://devzone.zend.com/12/php-101-part-8-databases-and-other-animals_part-1/)

Comment: but how do I use this in a php process

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, COUNT(comments.id) AS cnt
FROM users
LEFT JOIN comments ON users.id = comments.author_id
WHERE type IN ('forum', 'picture', 'news', 'etc')
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Get the 10 most prolific commenter where the comment type is 'form', 'picture', 'news', or 'etc'.

Comment: Oh its late... and I'm sleepy, but surely it should be GROUP BY users.id?

Comment: doh. right. I'll fix the grouping. LEFT JOIN handles the case where there's fewer than 10 commenters. An Inner join would only return as many rows as their are commenters.

Comment: if theres fewer than 10 commenters, i would assume you dont need to show anymore

Answer (score 1):

Tested on PostgreSQL 8.1:

```
select users.id, count(comments.author_id) 
from users, comments
where users.id = comments.author_id
group by users.id
order by 2 desc
```